# Render cycle in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a game engine written my my team, it's component based. It has logic components and visual components. In visual components there is a function named `updateVisual(delta)` and everything is drawn there.

For example, let's take physic ball entity in world:

```
class LogicBallComponent
{
   // ...
};

class VisualBallcomponent
{
   sfml::Texture mBallTexture;

   void updateVisual(float)
   {
       mBallTexture.translate(...);
       GlobalDisplayManager::instance().draw(mBallTexture);
   }
};
```

`GlobalDisplayManager` returns some window representation which creates gl-states, etc. (sf::RenderWindow in sfml). This system is easy to integrate.

Now I need to make android-game using my engine. I've chosen  cocos2d-x to use for window creation, rendering, fonts, resources etc.

There is another way to do the job:

```
class Ball : public CLayer
{
   bool Ball::init() {
      CSprite* sprite = CSprite::create(...);
      this->addChild(sprite, 0); // [!]
   }
};
```

And I don't know how to use it in my way. Is there such possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the function "void CCDisplayLinkDirector::mainLoop(void)", which is the main loop of coco2d-x rendering engine.

coco2d-x provides wrappers for periodic calling loop. In iOS you should check the function startMainLoop of CCDirectorCaller.mm in platform/ios.